# Branch Policies in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to add 3 reviewers for my code to merge from dev branch to master branch but I want it so that if 1 of the 3 reviewers approve the merge then my branches can merge. Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) you need to configure that 1 reviewer is required:

[image]

When you create the PR add many reviewers you want as optional:

[image]